# Why does bazel tests fail on Intel when bazel is built using bootstrap method?

Tags: bazel

While building Bazel v4.2.2, observed that some of the tests are failing on intel(ubuntu 18.04). Some of tests are observed to be passing on ci and some are excluded. The difference between the two is that - I have used bootstrapping method whereas on CI it does build using older Bazel binary. Below are the observations. Below tests are failing if I use bootstrap method but pass if Bazel is built using binary:
bazel_bootstrap_distfile_test
srcs_test
bazel_determinism_test
Tests which failed on intel but which are excluded from CI:
string_annotation_value_test
external_integration_test
workspace_resolved_test is failing in both the approaches. But the test is passing on CI. I was trying to find out why there are different test behaviors with respect to  bootstrap and binary method. But unable to get the differences. Could you please let me know if there is any known issue or workaround to make these tests pass or is it ok to ignore the tests failing with bootstrap method only or which are excluded from CI builds.

Comment: Why not install `bazel_4.2.2-linux-x86_64.deb` ..... Bazel releases are stored at sourceforge : https://phoenixnap.dl.sourceforge.net/project/bazel.mirror/4.2.2/bazel_4.2.2-linux-x86_64.deb → `sudo gdebi Downloads/4.2.2/bazel_4.2.2-linux-x86_64.deb` , and v4.2.1 was updated to 4.2.2 , Ubuntu 18.04 .

Comment: Thanks @KnudLarsen. I am interested in building on source for non-amd platform which doesn't have the binary. So this same behavior was also observed with amd and hence wanted to know the difference in bootstrap way and build using binary way like why the tests fail fail in the first approach and pass in the second.